# Why does "Failed to load resource" text show for "DOCTYPE HTML" tag with "/undefined?235" request in Symfony 2?

Tags: html, symfony, doctype, sonata

I've found an error in my Symfony2 website, what you can see below with the link:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B430tyHOr_s0SDdFXzJ2T1hVVEE&authuser=0

I use SonataPageBundle and SonataSeoBundle for html rendering, but I don't find the source of this bug.

Could anybody say something for this?

Regards,

Norbert